# How to skip injecting @Mock to test subject

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, easymock

```
@TestSubject
private SDTaServiceTypeField toTest;
@Mock
private SDTaComponentTagField commponentTagField;
@Mock
private SDTaComponentTypeField commponentTypeField;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    toTest = new SDTaServiceTypeField(wrapper);

    injectMocks(this);
```

As per the above code i have two mocks needs to be used by other services (not part of the test subject). As it is fitting to a Serializable instance its complaining

java.lang.RuntimeException: At least two mocks can be assigned to 'protected java.io.Serializable com.cisco.spvtg.rosa.vsm.common.tablefield.domain.PropertyDefBasedField.value': EasyMock for class com.cisco.spvtg.rosa.vsm.common.lineup.config.dcm.sicomponents.SDTaComponentTagField and EasyMock for class com.cisco.spvtg.rosa.vsm.common.lineup.config.dcm.sicomponents.SDTaComponentTypeField

How can i fix this ?

Comment: One option I can see don't add annotation for these two and @Before can use createMock to create them.. but looks like a work around not the solution

Comment: Did you try to use the fieldName property on the @Mock annotation?
http://easymock.org/api/org/easymock/Mock.html#fieldName--

Comment: filedName is not applicable here as its not applicable on the mock subject instance.

Comment: I get your point. You need a "do not inject" feature to allow only creating the mock. That could make sense. But it's weird to have a test subject and unrelated mocks in the same class. Maybe some test refactoring is required. But indeed, right now, the easier would be to remove @TestSubject and inject the mocks manually.